# How can a remote attacker find a user UID via Samba?

Tags: enumeration, samba

Is there a way to remotely retrieve the UID of a user via a Samba share?

I can get the user list with:

```
rpcclient -W 'WORKGROUP' -c querydispinfo -U''%'' '192.168.21.129' 2>&1

index: 0xa RID: 0x4c0 acb: 0x00000011 Account: foo Name: foo    Desc: (null)
```

Or I can cycle the RIDs with

```
rpcclient -W 'WORKGROUP' -c enumdomusers -U''%'' '192.168.21.129' 2>&1

user:[foo] rid:[0x4c0]
```

Or I can try and query the user directly:

```
rpcclient -W 'WORKGROUP' -U''%'' '192.168.21.129' -c 'lookupnames foo' 2>&1
foo S-1-5-21-1042354039-2475377354-766472396-1216 (User: 1)
```

However, I can't see a way to retrieve the user's UID.

Is this possible, short of finding an anonymous share that allows access to `/etc/passwd`?

Note that am asking from the point of view of an attacker enumerating the network and its users, not from the point of view of someone setting up a home Samba network.